# Arcade Expression for Feature Selection

Tags: arcade, arcgis-field-maps

I'm using Esri FieldMaps app to deploy a survey where staff will use a smart form in the app to enter info about a feature at the site. Much of the form is known data derived from a layer in the map, so once the form is initiated, there are form fields being populated automatically with Arcade expressions based on the user's location. This is is a good workflow for pulling the nearest feature's attributes into the new survey form entry, but I have a problem where there can be multiple coincident points with the same X/Y. I need them to be able to select which of the coincident points to pull data from for the new survey feature, but can not think of how that can be done with Arcade. This is the Arcade expression I'm harvesting to pull attributes from the nearest single (random) feature.

How do I allow for selection of the reference layer features so that field staff are pulling in the correct coincident features data? I think the spatial expression below is partway there, but the First() function is not selective; I would like it to be.

```
// If feature doesn't have geometry return null
if (IsEmpty(Geometry($feature))) { return null }

// Get the parcels layer
var parcels = FeatureSetByName($map, 'Parcels')

// Buffer the current location and intersect with parcels
var bufferedLocation = Buffer($feature, 100, 'feet')
var candidateParcels = Intersects(parcels, bufferedLocation)

// Calculate the distance between the parcel and the current location
// Store the feature and distance as a dictionary and push it into an array
var featuresWithDistances = []
for (var f in candidateParcels) {
    Push(featuresWithDistances, 
        {
            'distance': Distance($feature, f, 'feet'),
            'feature': f
        }
    )
}

// Sort the candidate parcels by distance using a custom function
function sortByDistance(a, b) {
    return a['distance'] - b['distance']
}
var sorted = Sort(featuresWithDistances, sortByDistance)

// Get the closest feature
var closestFeatureWithDistance = First(sorted)

// If there was no feature, return null
if (IsEmpty(closestFeatureWithDistance)) { return null }

// Return the address
return `${closestFeatureWithDistance['feature']['ADDNUM']} ${closestFeatureWithDistance['feature']['ADDRESSNAM']}`
```

Comment: What's the question here? You have a functional methodology, and haven't said what criteria you'd like to use to make the choice between multiple equidistant parcels non-arbitrary.

Comment: Edited to clarify what my question is.